# jQuery Draggable with overlapping PNG image

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, png, draggable

Is it possible to use jQuery's Draggable with an overlapping PNG image (not as a background image, too, as it needs to be printable)?  I've tried the CSS style "pointer-events: none," but this doesn't work in IE.

```
<div id="overlap">
     <img src="overlapping.png" />
</div>

<div id="draggable">
     <img src="photoToDrag.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: How is it that the overlap is overlapping?  The HTML alone would seem to suggest that these are adjacent elements.  How are they positioned? That is, are they position absolute? or floating?

Comment: They would be using position absolute and z-index to ensure that the "overlap" div is on top.  The container (not shown in the above code) would be using position relative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We finally solved this problem by adding mouse event listeners to the overlay div, and then passing those events to the image.  So, any time the PNG overlay `("#frame")` is clicked, that click event is passed through to the underlying image `("#imageid")`.  With this solution, we can make the underlying image draggable without the overlay blocking it.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#imageid" ).draggable();

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind any events needed to the #frame element.
    $("#frame").bind("click", function (event) {
        proxy(event);
    });

    $("#frame").bind("mousedown", function (event) {
        proxy(event);
    });

    $("#frame").bind("mouseup", function (event) {
        proxy(event);
    });

    $("#frame").bind("mousemove", function (event) {
        proxy(event);
    });
});

function proxy(event) {
    $("#imageid").trigger(event);
}
```

The HTML would be setup like:

```
<div id="image">
    <img id="imageid" src="imageToDrag.jpg" style="position: relative; visibility: visible;">
</div>
<div id="frame">
    <img src="overlay.png" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0; height: 100px; width: 100px;"/>
</div>
```